# Android BLE services onServiceDiscover() is not being called

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Ble is advertising AdvertiseData added in BluetoothGattServer and advertise is done and device get connected. after connect discoverServices() is also called but services are not discovered i.e. onServiceDiscovered() callback not triggered.

//**BluetoothGatt client work fine with Google sample Adevertiser** that i have **tested** but server side i have added BluetoothGattServer code below listed

//ADVERTISER CODE 
/**
     * Starts BLE Advertising.
     */

```
private void startAdvertising() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Service: Starting Advertising");

    if (mAdvertiseCallback == null) {
        AdvertiseSettings settings = buildAdvertiseSettings();
        AdvertiseData data = buildAdvertiseData();
        mAdvertiseCallback = new SampleAdvertiseCallback();

        if (mBluetoothLeAdvertiser != null) {
            mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, mAdvertiseCallback);
        }
    }
}
```

//GATT SERVER creating gatt server instance attaching services and characteristics that are going to expose

```
private void initServer() {
     BluetoothGattService service =
            new BluetoothGattService(Constants.Service_UUID,BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);

    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
            new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(Constants.Char_UUID,
                    //Read + write characteristics and permission
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE,
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);

    service.addCharacteristic(characteristic);
    mBluetoothGattServer.addService(service);
}
```

// Callbacks to handle all Gatt client connection to handle read + write request

```
private BluetoothGattServerCallback mBGattServerCallback = new BluetoothGattServerCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothDevice device, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(device, status, newState);
        Log.d(TAG ,"OnConnection state change");
        if(newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED){

        }else  if(newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED){

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceAdded(int status, BluetoothGattService service) {
        super.onServiceAdded(status, service);
        Log.i(TAG, " Service are added");
    }
```

//Advertise data

```
private AdvertiseData buildAdvertiseData() {
```

`AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
                .addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(Constants.Service_UUID))
                .build();
}`

//Advertise setting

```
private AdvertiseSettings buildAdvertiseSettings() {
    AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
            .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED)
            .setConnectable(true)
            .setTimeout(0)
            .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_MEDIUM)
            .build();
    return settings;
```

}

//Get references to system Bluetooth objects if we don't have them already.

```
private void initialize() {
    if (mBluetoothLeAdvertiser == null) {
        BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        if (mBluetoothManager != null) {
            BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
            if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
                mBluetoothLeAdvertiser = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
                //register the instance of server to BLE framework
                mBluetoothGattServer = mBluetoothManager.openGattServer(this,mBGattServerCallback);
                initServer();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.bt_null), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.bt_null), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

//Log summery

`
    // the service uuid and characteristics uuid are coming into advertisment data
{
onGetService() - Device=65:5E:34:E1:47:55 UUID=0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805xxxx
                  10-31 17:55:11.542 23276-25749/
 D/BluetoothGatt: onGetService() - Device=65:5E:34:E1:47:55 UUID=0000xxxx-0000-
                  1000-8000-0080xxxxx

onGetCharacteristic() - Device=65:5E:34:E1:47:55 UUID=0000xxxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805fxxxxx srvcType=0 srvcInstId=0 charInstId=0 charProps=32
10-31 17:55:11.627 23276-23290/
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetCharacteristic() - Device=65:5E:34:E1:47:55 UUID=0000xxx-0000-1000-8000-00805fxxxx srvcType=0 srvcInstId=0 charInstId=1 charProps=10
10-31 17:55:11.718 23276-23289/
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetCharacteristic() - Device=65:5E:34:E1:47:55 UUID=0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805fxxxxx srvcType=0 srvcInstId=0 charInstId=0 charProps=2
}
`

Comment: share your code

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Share your code plz.

Answer (score 1):

**Device change**
i was testing with micromax canvas as Central.
now i changed device and here service are discovered and got callback..

**BUT**
writeCharacteristics() request, server(remote device) is not triggering callback onCharacteristicsReadRequest() as i was performing only write operation for required characteristics. nothing else to refuse operation.